# How to calculate GEO (geostationary) satellite eclipse time?

Tags: geostationary, earth, solar-eclipse

The positions of satellites in geostationary orbits can be characterized by their longitude, the longitude of a point on Earth's equator that is nadir to the spacecraft.

Satellites in GEO will sometimes enter the Earth's shadow and experience solar eclipse. Since the Earth's equator is inclined so far from the ecliptic, this eclipsing depends on the time of year as well.

Are there some simple equations that can estimate the star and end times of solar eclipse for a satellite in GEO, based on the satellite's longitude and the time of year?

Alternatively, are there resources available that can be used to make more accurate predictions?

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for attention. Actually the number of formulas does not matter to me. As a result I want to solve the problem.

Comment: e-books, c #, Jscript, or python. But I need to find the way to calculate. I can probably solve it by formula. @uhoh

Comment: @uhoh I write question on [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/). I hope someone will reply.

Comment: I've been thinking so much about the upcoming **lunar eclipse** that I completely missed the point that this is about the eclipse of an *artificial satellite*. It doesn't belong in Astronomy, it does belong here. However, I think the question will still be closed here and still needs some improvement.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a bit more suitable for the site. Hopefully this pretty close to what you would like to ask.

Comment: Actually, the process is no different than for a common lunar eclipse; the "geostationary" quirk just means a specific orbit of our "moon", and "artificial" makes it very small, difference between partial and complete eclipse negligible.

Comment: what I need is to find out what time satellite going into the umbra. So, I search any formula, tools and etc. @sf

Answer (score 2):

There are several web-base calculators available.  [This one](https://www.satellite-calculations.com/Satellite/satellite_eclipse.htm) seems to work well; there's [more explanation here](https://www.satellite-calculations.com/Satellite/satellite_suneclipse_info.htm).

(Generaly, SE answers aren't supposed to be just links, in case the link dies, but I'm not sure what else to say about an online calculator:  If the link dies, there's no calculator to use)

Comment: I must find any formula(s) or tools. What I need is the entrance and exit time to the dark side of the Earth.